# How to open bzr diff using Meld with multiple tabs?

Tags: command-line, bazaar, meld

How can I simultaneously open all Bazaar file diffs in multiple tabs within the same Meld window?

Currently, I execute the following command to use Meld to view Bazaar changes:

```
bzr diff --using meld
```

When there are multiple files with changes, Meld opens the first file, but not the others. Then, when I exit the Meld window, the diff for the next file opens in a new Meld window. This continues until I've viewed all files with diffs.

Note: I have also tried the following, but it behaved the same as above.

```
bzr diff --using meld &
```

Comment: I believe bzr itself runs through the diffs one file at a time (similar to how git goes through merge conflicts one file at a time).

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand we need to pass new tab creation argument to the Meld.

According to its man-page this feature exists [in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (see `man meld`)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/meld.1.html) and above:

> **NAME**
>   `meld` - Visual diff and merge tool for the GNOME Desktop
>   ...
>   **OPTIONS**
>   ...
>   `--newtab`, `-n`
>                Open the comparison as a new tab in an already-running instance.

So we need to pass `--newtab` option to `meld`:

```
meld --newtab /etc/os-release /etc/os-release &
meld --newtab /etc/os-release /etc/os-release &
```

In Bazaar case we need to find corresponding option in `bzr diff` subcommand.
According to [`man bzr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bzr.1.html) we should use `--diff-options` option:

> **NAME**
>   `bzr` - Bazaar next-generation distributed version control
>   **COMMAND REFERENCE**
>   `bzr diff [FILE...]`
>    ...
>          `--diff-options ARG`        Pass these options to the external diff program.

Possible solution:

```
bzr diff --using meld --diff-options --newtab &
bzr diff --using meld --diff-options --newtab &
```

But in real situation as stated by OP it does not work.
So we need to create an alias for this command:

```
for f in $( eval "bzr stat --versioned" ); \
do eval "bzr diff --using meld --diff-options --newtab ${f} &"; \
done
```

Comment: This really looked like it would work, but it didn't. However, using your command in a loop seems to work: `for f in $( eval "bzr stat --versioned" ); do eval "bzr diff --using meld --diff-options --newtab ${f} &"; done`. Perhaps I could create an alias to this.